# Username in URL after domain

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to get a user dashboard just like Instagram or Facebook has after their domain names. Example https://facebook.com/the.hardik.sisodia.page

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('{username}', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('dashboard');

Route::get('contact', [ContactController::class, 'index'])->name('contact');
```

**Controller**

```php
$user = User::where('username', $username)->get();

if (isset($user[0])) {
    $data = [
        'user' => $user ? $user : abort(404),
    ];
    
    return view('frontend.user.dashboard', $data);
} else {
    abort(404);
}
```

**Issue**

When I attempt to view the Contact page, I cannot view it because of a 404 error page not found. I don't understand where I am going wrong. I also tried to group dashboard route using `{username}` as a prefix in the route group but still faced the same issue.

Comment: The problem is in the ordering of your routes.

Comment: Whoa this made it work. Thanks @Unflux

Answer (score 0):

As you're getting a parameter in your route address, you may have route conflicts.

Try adding a unique name before your route address, something like adding *profile* before the route

```
Route::get('profile/{username}', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
```